# Extracting a gz file content with zlib and save it

Tags: c++, zlib, compression

I want to uncompress a gz file (e.g. "MyFile.gz") and saving its content in a specified path using zlib in C++.

In other words, if the path is "C:\StoredData\", I would like to write a C++ function that creates the file "C:\StoredData\MyFile"

How can I write it?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what is the problem here.
Once the data is uncompressed, you can write it anywhere you want using the File Stream.
If you are facing any issues, you can edit your post.
Sorry to post as answer, as i can't add comments.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation in [zlib.h](http://zlib.net/manual.html).  The `gz*` functions will do what you want on the uncompression side.  Then you just write the uncompressed data wherever you like.